# Docker Node With Multiple IP Addresses - Switching Between Them

Tags: networking, docker

My network configuration looks something like this on a docker host:

```
➜  server git:(master) ✗ ip addr
3: ens9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:02:c9:bb:3b:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet <IP Address>.18/29 brd <Default Gateway>.23 scope global ens9
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet <IP Address>.19/29 brd <Default Gateway>.23 scope global secondary ens9:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Currently, I have existing non-Docker services running on port `443` on the `.18` IP address, and I need to keep it that way. However, when I open a port using a `Dockerfile`, it fails to start because port `443` is already in use by the host.

Is there a way to globally switch the IP address that Docker uses when opening a port up? I do not want to have to set this manually on each container's configuration file, which of course already works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to expose ports to access certain containers on the service declaration. In fact, you can declare a network inside a single docker-compose.yml with a different subnet like this:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  custom-network:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 73.0.0.0/16
          ip_range: 73.0.0.0/24
          gateway: 73.0.0.254

services:
  simple-nginx:
    image: nginx
    networks:
      custom-network:
        ipv4_address: 73.0.0.10
```

And access the nginx service using the static IP `73.0.0.10` for the custom-network.

For more information, you can always check the networking docs for docker-compose:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Or directly the docker docs:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

Comment: Do I have to do this in the `docker-compose.yml` file? This would make the containers incredibly non-portable. Is there a global way to do this on the Docker host?

Comment: The docker-compose is just a simple way to declare the services. You can always declare the network `docker network create --subnet 78.0.0.0/16 --ip-range 78.0.0.0/24 --gateway 78.0.0.254 custom-network` and then join the container in the network: `docker network connect custom-network your-container`